# Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

my app couldn't start it crashes immediately after i installed it and i couldn't understand the error!

> > i have created two recylcerView for two fragments which are attached in the main activity xml file

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.invincible.fragfrag, PID: 14384
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.invincible.fragfrag/com.invincible.fragfrag.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                      at com.invincible.fragfrag.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.invincible.fragfrag-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                      at com.invincible.fragfrag.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView" on path:
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.invincible.fragfrag;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.table_number_list) == null) {
            TableNumber tableNumber=TableNumber.getTableNumber("number");
            FragmentTransaction transaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.table_number_list,tableNumber);
            transaction.commit();

        }
        if  (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.table_values) == null) {
            TableValue tableValue=TableValue.getTableValue("value");
            FragmentTransaction transaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.table_values,tableValue);
            transaction.commit();


        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

main xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.invincible.fragfrag.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_one"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView>
    <android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_two"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

plz help me out what's the error and how to handle two fragment with two recyclerview in one activity.

THANK YOU for your concern!

Comment: is this a mistake with `android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView`
do you mean `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

Comment: you can see my error log above

Comment: but you are not using a `RecylerView`, try to replace your `android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView` to `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

use this code in your xml file to create a listview. Simple!

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to use `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`.

#### Additional info that you *don't* need to know

`RecycleListView` is a nested class of `android.support.v7.app.AlertController`. One would refer to it as `android.support.v7.app.AlertController$RecycleListView` (the dollar sign). This is why it crashed at this point.

`RecycleListView` extends `ListView` not `RecyclerView`. That's why it would later crash with `ClassCastException` when you would try to use it in Java.

`RecycleListView` is an internal class of appcompat-v7 not to be used in your project.

Answer (score 3):

I made the same mistake. Try to replace

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
```

with

```
 android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```