# What is alertcontroller.recyclelistview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

What is alertcontroller.recyclelistview ? How it differ from Normal RecyclerView and What are the new Features and How to use it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to other questions asked, links below, RecyclerListView is an internal class which is not intended for use other than a code block for other classes.
I can't find any document about it in [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/index.html?q=recyclerlistview) as well.
Hope it clarifies a little bit.

[Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283764/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-app-alertcontroller-recyclelistview)

[difference between android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView and android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157529/difference-between-android-support-v7-app-alertcontroller-recyclelistview-and-an)