# difference between android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView and android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I recently update my Android Studio and also SDK. In new Android Studio, there is `android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView`. I am familiar with `android.support.v7.RecyclerView`, so I am a little bit confused that what is the difference between these two. If anyone can guide then it would be thankful.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

RecycleListView is an internal class not intended for external use. The fact that it is showing up publicly in the support library is probably a mistake.

You can see here in the regular (non-appcompat) version it is an internal class <strike>http://developer.oesf.biz/em/developer/reference/eggplant/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.RecycleListView.html</strike>

edit: The old link is no longer available. Here is the archive.org version: https://web.archive.org/web/20170604100431/http://developer.oesf.biz/em/developer/reference/eggplant/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.RecycleListView.html

Comment: link doesnot open