# Difference between recyclerView and recyclerListView?

Tags: android-recyclerview, difference, between

.Difference between recyclerView and recyclerListView. recyclerListView is ListView?? or both are same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView and android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157529/difference-between-android-support-v7-app-alertcontroller-recyclelistview-and-an)

Comment: You may refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728651/recyclerview-vs-listview

Comment: I know difference between listView and recyclerView. I have android 2.3.3, when i extend recyclerView in my Java class it always pick recyclerListView instead of recyclerView, i already implement recyclerView in my gradle file. I only want to know can i use recyclerListView instead of recyclerView?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157529/difference-between-android-support-v7-app-alertcontroller-recyclelistview-and-an