# Error Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k2xj.png)

I am creating a chat in android studio, when I run the program everything comes up with green chekes, but in the log I get the following error and send me to correct the problem in the Main Activity, in the emoludar opens the application and closes it.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mensajeria.chatappsistema, PID: 11008
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mensajeria.chatappsistema/mensajeria.chatappsistema.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.app.AlertController$RecycleListView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.app.AlertController$RecycleListView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        at mensajeria.chatappsistema.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
Application terminated.
```

Comment: send full error log and layout. 
there could be an issue in implementing the view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42418632/2711811

Comment: "... android.support.v7.app.AlertController$RecycleListView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView ..." but you do that in line 38 of your MainActivity.

Comment: Questions should be written (by the Question author!!) in English. If you cannot do this, consider posting your Questions on https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

In XML file you are using different recyclerview and java you are casting different recyclerview that's why the error is coming. Use the same type of recyclerview in both XML and java file.

Comment: Is correct, The problem was solved with your solution, thanks